# Lucene Out Of Memory

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

I'm using Lucene `v4.10.4`. I have pretty big index, it could be over few GBs. So I get `OutOfMemoryError` on initializing `IndexSearcher`:

```
try (Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath))) { 

    //Out of Memory here!
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(indexDir));
```

*How to tell Lucene's DirectoryReader to not load into memory more than 256 MB at once?*

### Log

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.BytesStore.<init>(BytesStore.java:68)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.FST.<init>(FST.java:386)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.FST.<init>(FST.java:321)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.FieldReader.<init>(FieldReader.java:85)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsReader.<init>(BlockTreeTermsReader.java:192)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene41.Lucene41PostingsFormat.fieldsProducer(Lucene41PostingsFormat.java:441)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsReader.<init>(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:197)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat.fieldsProducer(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentCoreReaders.<init>(SegmentCoreReaders.java:120)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.<init>(SegmentReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$1.doBody(StandardDirectoryReader.java:62)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:923)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:53)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:67)
```

Comment: Maybe it would be worth thinking about either giving more memory to the JVM or implementing your custom IndexReader for directories.

Comment: @Catalin yeah, that's the issue with minimal RAM threshold. Actually I have fixed it with increasing RAM

Answer (score 1):

First you should check the current heap size of your JVM.

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep MaxHeapSize
```

If this number is not reasonable for your use case, you should increase it when running your program with -Xmx option of java command. A sample command to assign 8GB of heap memory would look like:

```
java -Xmx8g -jar your_jar_file
```

Hope this helps.